# nameserver doesn't work stable

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, connection

I've recently bought 2 domains from namesilo. I'm using a VPS on AWS.

https://duman.digital and https://dumandigital.com

Both are using the same nameservers, same settings, however dumandigital.com is always reachable by anyone, meanwhile duman.digital is kind of broken.

My friends can't open it. I can't open it from my phone but I can open it from PC. (Same WiFi)

Phone throws an error: `server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Meanwhile PC just works:

[image: pc view]

If I enable my VPN (Google Cloud VPS) and try, PC doesn't work anymore either.

```
Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

We can’t connect to the server at duman.digital.
If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:

Try again later.
Check your network connection.
If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Firefox has permission to access the Web.
```

I tried some tools like MXToolbox to see the issue: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3aduman.digital&run=toolpage

Result is: `Sorry, we couldn't find any name servers for 'duman.digital'`

My questions are:

- How can I connect with certain combinations.
- Why dumandigital.com never fails.
- How do I solve this issue? (Both domains are using the very same config.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this

```
$ host -va 'duman.digital.' 
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
duman.digital.          14400   IN      MX      10 mail.duman.digital.
duman.digital.          14400   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx ip4:18.196.180.31 ~all"
duman.digital.          14400   IN      SOA     ns1.dumanstudios.com. root.duman.digital. 2018080506 7200 3600 1209600 180
duman.digital.          14400   IN      NS      ns2.dumanstudios.com.
duman.digital.          14400   IN      A       18.196.180.31
```

So `ns2.dumanstudios.com.` is the only nameserver listed. The `ns1.dumanstudios.com.` from `SOA` is should be named in an `NS` entry if it supposed to be queried.

But both `ns2.dumanstudios.com.` and `ns1.dumanstudios.com.` can't be resolved:

```
Host ns2.dumanstudios.com. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Host ns1.dumanstudios.com. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

So the answer above must come directly from a server serving `digital.`. This is an error in the DNS setup. If you control the DNS, specify the actual nameservers. Otherwise get your provider to fix it.